# Default color scheme of Spectrogram

Tags: sound, plot-themes

`Spectrogram`s seem to use the "SunsetColors" color scheme.  That being said, I can't figure out exactly how it is being applied; the `Graphics` produced is of a three channel `Raster` (so a linear gradient `ColorData` does not work).  Strangely if we use `GrayLevel` on each pixel triple, we get a sensible looking plot:

```
ArrayPlot[FirstCase[spec,Raster[x_NumericArray,___]:>x,\[Infinity]],ColorFunction->GrayLevel]
```

[image: simspec]

Again, this is an attempt to understand how `Spectrogram` uses its DFT data to do the plot.  In the end my goal is to do something similar to MMA's image previewer which highlights the exact RGB value of an image (but instead we get the intensity at an exact frequency and time of an audio file).  I have much of this implemented stemming from `MousePosition["Graphics"]`, and I think this is the final hurdle to making it work.

To make this a concrete question, how can I map a particular pixel value to its 'sunset-color'?  Neither `GrayLevel` nor `ColorData["SunsetColors"]` work, although `GrayLevel` semi-does in the `ArrayPlot` batch case.

Comment: The function that produces the spectrogram raster is ``Sound`samplesToSpectrogramRaster``. You can see its content using ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[Sound`samplesToSpectrogramRaster]``.